# python: run two scripts with arguments simultaneously

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing

What I have is:

```
import main
import branies

if __name__ == "__main__":
    WEEKDAYS = [1,2,3,4,5]
    for day in WEEKDAYS:
        pd = foo(day)
        main.main(pd)
        branies.main(pd)
```

I intend to run both `main.main` and `branies.main` simultaneously with the argument `pd`

what i tried:

```
subprocess.run("python3 main.py -a {0} & python3 branies.py -a {0}".format(pd), shell=True)
```

but this fails to pass the argument, error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 361, in <module>
  File "branies.py", line 355, in <module>
    main()
    main()
TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pd'
TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pd'
```

debugging:

```
print("python3 main.py -a {0} & python3 branies.py -a {0}".format(pd))
```

output:

```
python3 main.py -a 2020-02-24 & python3 branies.py -a 2020-02-24
```

EDIT:

```
import main
import branies
```

both main and branies are two python scripts with functions `main(pd=None)` in them which expects the parameter `pd`

Comment: can you please write more details about your main function, the problem is still not that much clear

Comment: @MohammadRijwan please check the edit

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want to accomplish, but perhaps something like this would do it:

`script1.py` and `script2.py` (I think your `main.py` and `branies.py`):

```
import sys
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

def main(pd):
    sleep(5) # doing some computations
    print(f"time={datetime.now()}, arg={pd}") # also adding "script {1 or 2}" to print statement 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arg = sys.argv[1]
    main(arg)
```

`main.py`:

```
import subprocess

for pd in [1,2,3]:
    subprocess.run(
        f"python3 script1.py {pd} & python3 script2.py {pd}", 
    shell=True)
```

From terminal: `python main.py`; output:

```
time=2020-08-16 11:39:17.911350, script 1, arg=1
time=2020-08-16 11:39:17.911350, script 2, arg=1
time=2020-08-16 11:39:22.931387, script 1, arg=2
time=2020-08-16 11:39:22.931387, script 2, arg=2
time=2020-08-16 11:39:27.951381, script 1, arg=3
time=2020-08-16 11:39:27.951358, script 2, arg=3
```

Comment: i get the error: TypeError: __call__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Could you perhaps show me some relevant code from your main.py or branies.py? EDIT: Can you run your scripts (main.py/branies.py) separately?

Comment: There might be an issue somewhere in your scripts (a __call__ method is given 3 arguments but only accepts 1 or 2).

Comment: but we're using the run method not the call method at all

Comment: Is my understanding of your question correct (see answer provided above)? Namely, that you have two scripts, both of which take an argument (e.g. `sys.argv[1]`). And inside both of these scripts you have a `main` function that accepts an argument (so `sys.argv[1]` should be passed to main). And finally, you would like to have a third script that runs both of these scripts passing the argument (e.g. `subprocess.run(f"python3 script1.py {arg} & python3 script2.py {arg}")`)?

Comment: I would also like to know if you can [successfully] run your scripts (main.py/branies.py) separately? Again, assuming that I've understood your question correctly, there might be an issue with/in your scripts (some method that's receiving too many arguments).